# Compare path of url strings. Ignoring domain names

Tags: java, uri

In Java, I want to compare two strings which are basically the urls, so if the endpoints are same and the domain is different it should return true.
For example: https://www.example.org/dl/pi/1 should be a valid match with http://1.1.1.1/dl/pi/1

Comment: one is http and other is https?

Comment: Parse the two and compare only the parts that are interesting?  Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: yup, I also want to ignore http or https etc while comparing, but it should make assure that it a valid url format.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include additional information as well as your code

Comment: I am thinking the approach where I will use regex to ignore the domain name while comparison.

Comment: Please don't use regex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564998/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-url#5565025

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
String url1 = new URL("http://1.1.1.1/dl/pi/1").getPath(); // returns /dl/pi/1
String url2 = new URL("https://www.example.org/dl/pi/1").getPath(); // returns /dl/pi/1

System.out.println(url1.equals(url2));
```

If the `URL` is not correct it'll throw `MalformedURLException`.

Javadoc can be found [here | URL.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)